# sound device is not shown after purging pulseaudio

Tags: sound, vlc, indicator-sound

I installed `pulseaudio-equlizer` to increase the quality of sound in my laptop. But after installing it, when playing videos in `vlc player` sound volume got increased and got decreased from time to time automatically, just like manually doing it. I thought that may be due to the newly installed `pulseaudio` so I uninstall it through `apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio`
 found on [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489609/how-can-i-cleanly-remove-pulseaudio-in-ubuntu-14-04) after that when I restart my lap, sound icon is not shown in the top right corner and `sound device` is not shown in the `sounds` in the `settings`. Please help me to fix this error, as I can't reinstall the `OS` again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio` to install it again

Comment: @Suici Doga it says `pulseaudio is already the newest version.` why is that

Comment: Try removing and installing it

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for it.
First I removed any traces of pulseaudio and pulseaudio-equalizer by using the below command

```
sudo apt purge pulseaudio pulseaudio-equalizer
```

then

removed following directories using the following command

```
rm -rf /etc/pulse /usr/share/pulseaudio usr/share/pulseaudio-equalizer
```

then `reboot` the system.
Next reinstalled `pulseaudio` using the following code

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio
```

(internet connection is needed)
finally reinstalled `elementary-dekstop` using the following command

```
sudo apt install elementary-desktop
```

---

after reboot, move aside the ~/.config/pulse folder
(on a Elementary OS 'Loki' system, audio device was still missing until I did this step; immediately after I deleted the pulse folder, the default sound device reappeared as desired)

```
cd ~/.config/pulse && tar -zcf pulse.tar.gz pulse && rm -rf pulse
```